# wcin and cin in same program to read user input

Tags: c++, c++11, cin, wchar-t

I know it is not recommended to use both narrow and wide character versions of the same stream (e.g., `cin` and `wcin`), but I need exactly this functionality.

How can I read user input safely in the same program into both narrow and wide characters?

Here is a (bad) sample program, which after reading in and printing out `wch`, is done. Does not wait for inputting `ch`, possibly reads some garbage, and does not print anything.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wchar_t wch[10];
    char     ch[10];

    wcin >> wch;
    wcout << wch;
    cin >> ch;
    cout << ch;
}
```

What would be an acceptable version of the above program that handles narrow and wide inputs (and outputs)? (Don't bother with size safety!) Thanks!

Comment: It's not "not recommended". It's simply not allowed.

Comment: IIRC the console to which the program is attached is either full Unicode or ANSI code page not both.

Comment: I see, but then how to simply print a `string` if I use `wcout`?

Comment: use `std::wstring` instead of  `std::string`, which is also defined in `<string>`